# Vim screen being overwritten by console messages

Tags: vim, zsh

I'm on a chromebook and can only have one terminal open, I'm sshing into my arch linux server and using vim and flask (as python development web server) (in background). The console messages from flask are overwriting my screen in vim.

So, the text from the file I'm editing is being blocked out by text from the terminal.

How can I prevent this? Running flask silently or something else?

Comment: Use `tmux` or `screen` on the Linux machine.

Comment: `(flask run --host=0.0.0.0 &) &> /dev/null` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You can establish two ssh shells simultaneously (there's no restriction on doing this).

From one you'll vim, from second - flask.

Two different terminals should do the trick. Check please [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1032251/multiple-ssh-connections-to-the-same-system-is-it-possible) answer on superuser

Comment: I'm on a chromebook and can only have one terminal open

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/708811/can-i-use-a-chromebook-as-a-ssh-workstation - this one also may stay in help

Answer (score 1):

When you run background tasks in the same terminal that's running Vim, both processes will compete for the terminal, and override each other's screen.

In Vim, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or `:redraw`) will clean up the mess, but it's better to avoid this situation altogether by redirecting the background tasks into a file (which could then be `:split` inside Vim) or the *null device* (if you're not interested in the output).

```
flask ... > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
flask ... &> /dev/null
```